# search registration through the year and month

Tags: php, html, css, sql, date

I'm making a code where a record has to appear through the date (Month, Year), for example: 12-2022. But this is where it is, with this code, I'm not getting it. What can I do?

```
<?php
                
                $sqli=sprintf("SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE YEAR(data) = 2022/10");
                $resu=mysqli_query($con,$sqli);
                mysqli_set_charset($con, 'UTF8');
?>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM eventos WHERE YEAR(data) = 2022 AND MONTH(data) = 10`. Can you please stop deleting questions where people already answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause should be separated on year and month.

The query that might work is some thing like this:

```
"select * from eventos where year(data) = '2022' and month(data) = 10"
```